# Relativity of simultaneity in flat spacetime

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, observers

In Einstein’s (1917) thought experiment on the relativity of simultaneity…

The lightening flashes at A and B are both equal distance from the center of the train and the center of the platform.
The platform observer sees the light from A and B arrive simultaneously.
The train observer sees the light from B arrive before the light from A.

Move these two frames of reference into flat spacetime and please explain why the platform is not the moving frame that sees the light from A before the light from B.

**Edited for clarity**

reference:
https://archive.org/details/Albert_Einstein__The_Special_and_General_Theory/page/n23/mode/2up

Einstein explains the kinematics as follows:

*“When we say that the lightning strokes A and B are simultaneous with respect to be embankment, we mean: the rays of light emitted at the places A and B, where the lightning occurs, meet each other at the mid-point M of the length A-> B of the embankment. **But
the events A and B also correspond to positions A and B on the train.**”**
*(my emphasis)*

When explaining the kinematics observed from the frame of the train he says

*“Now in reality (considered with reference to the railway embankment) he is hastening towards the beam of light coming from B, whilst he is riding on ahead of the beam of light coming from A. Hence the observer will see the beam of light emitted from B earlier than he will see that emitted from A.“*

As per my original question:

Why is the relative motion between the train and the platform showing a preference for which finds the simultaneity in the observations of the same two events?
Einstein says “in reality” the train is moving toward the beam of light coming from B and away from the beam of light coming from A. But in reality he has also said the motion of the train is a relative measure. As far as the laws are concerned, the platform is moving relative to the train. So which frame is moving toward and away from the beams of light coming from B and A respectively?
Why is only one frame stipulated as having this motion relative to the light beams when both frames are in relative motion?

Comment: *Move these two frames of reference into flat spacetime.* Are you suggesting that the Earth’s gravity is involved in this?

Comment: 4 downvotes? I like the question. Everyone knows the train/platform lightning thing, and the question indicates some standard biases (in my experience, at least), that are common conceptual blocks when making the jump to Minkowski space. I think we're here to clear those up for ppl who want to learn.

Comment: The OP is puzzled by the "asymmetry", but the question has _made_ the situation asymmetric.  The cloud causing the lightning is _clearly_ to be understood as stationary  WRT the platform.  If it were instead tracking the motion of the train, then the asymmetry would be reversed.  As usual, the "clutter" (whether stated or unstated) in these "cute" examples is getting in the way.

Comment: _"explain why the platform is not the moving frame that sees the light from A before the light from B."_ - because that is not how the thought experiment is defined. In the though experiment, the lighting strikes are such that platform observer sees them in at the same time. Any other observation would be a different thought experiment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are biasing the platform's frame, $S$, (at rest with respect to Earth) as being more at rest than the train, which is stationary in the train frame, $S'$.

So forget the Earth:

The reason the flashes are simultaneous in $S$ is because they are defined to simultaneous in $S$, and since $S'$ is moving wrt to $S$: they are not simultaneous in $S'$. I don't know which way the train is moving, nor at which end the events $A$ and $B$ occur--note: the lightning strikes represent points in spacetime, which are called events.

The Lorentz transform is unambiguous; if:

$$ A = (t=0, x=0)_S $$
$$ B = (0, L)_S $$

(NB: $L \ne L_0$)

then in $S'$ (moving towards $B$):

$$ A = (0,0)_{S'} $$
$$ B = (-\gamma\beta L, \gamma L)_{S'}$$

So $B$ happens first (with $\beta \gt 0$).

Addendum: So, in the question, you state that the observer sees $A$ and $B$ simultaneously, so I assumed w/o derivation that means $A$ and $B$ are simultaneous in $S$--it does. You may want to show that (hint: move the origin, I chose the caboose so I could do the math in my head).

I think one of the conceptual blocks you may have is associating events  with a particular frame, so, that at $t>0$ (after the strikes) thinking the  position at which they occurred still matters. For example, once $A$ occurs at $(0,0)_S$ there is nothing special about $x=0$. Yes, the platform observer could say the world line of the strike is $(t, 0)$ for $t \ge 0$, but the train observer could claim the strike location moves with him, at $(t'\ge 0, 0)_{S'} $.

Events don't have a frame, they are unambiguous points in spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming there is a 'preference', which is nonsense. The point is that the two flashes can be simultaneous in the frame of the platform, in which case the traveller on the train will see them at different times, or they can be simultaneous in the frame of the train, in which case the platform observer will see them at two different times. Either scenario is possible.

The underlying principle might be easier for you to understand if you imagine a very long train moving past a very long platform. Time all along the train is out of synch with time all along the platform. At the front of the train it might be 12:00 on the train and 12:01 on the platform, while at the rear it might be 12:00 on the train and 11:59 on the platform, so two flashes that happen at 12:00 in train time will happen at 12:01 and 11:59 in platform time. Conversely, when it is 12:00 at the rear of the platform it is 12:01 at the rear of the train, and when it is 12:00 at the front of the platform it is 11:59 on the train, so that two flashes that occur at 12:00 in platform time occur at two different times in train time.

Answer (score 1):

> Move these two frames of reference into flat spacetime

Nothing in Einstein’s analysis involves tidal gravity. It is already in flat spacetime.

> explain why the platform is not the moving frame that sees the light from A before the light from B

That is a given in the problem setup. Lightning happens more or less randomly. It is certainly possible for two strikes to occur simultaneously in the platform frame by chance. We then simply analyze the situation given that what could have happened did happen.

It is also possible for two strikes to occur simultaneously in the train frame. We could instead do the same analysis given that the strikes occurred simultaneously in the train frame. To do so, simply exchange every occurrence of “train” and “platform”, and exchange every occurrence of “B” and “A”.

The important conclusion remains the same either way. What is simultaneous in one frame is not simultaneous in the other frame.

> Einstein says “in reality” the train is moving toward the beam of light coming from B and away from the beam of light coming from A. But in reality he has also said the motion of the train is a relative measure.

Indeed, that is poor wording. The words “in reality” do not affect the math in any way, so they would have been better dropped. And as you said, the train frame is equally “real”. Don’t get hung up on that poor word choice. It is irrelevant to the point of the scenario.

> So which frame is moving toward and away from the beams of light coming from B and A respectively?

The train is moving toward and away from the light in the platform frame.

The platform is moving toward and away from the light in the train frame.

We could have done the analysis in either frame, so we chose the platform frame. Either way reaches the same conclusion: what is simultaneous in one frame is not simultaneous in the other.

Comment: I understand and agree with everything you have said, so please don’t assume this is an argument. 
I am questioning what appears to me to be a contradiction. Clearly I have not understood something.

Comment: @PHccID it is not a contradiction, it is a choice. Einstein could have analyzed any scenario. He chose to analyze this scenario. What is difficult to understand about that?

Comment: I don't think you can move towards or away from a beam of light. If you observe the light, it is moving towards you.

Comment: @JEB well, if I am chased by a hungry cheetah I am certainly going to move away from it. So why not light? Its speed is invariant, but it is still a speed. Anyway, they were the OPs words, used to indicate direction of motion. I think they are sufficiently clear as to not warrant objection

Comment: @Dale so I try to address it in my answer, but there is an inherent bias to think that a photon (or plane wave) has some association with the frame in which it was emitted (and this is true in spectroscopy, astronomy, CMB/cosmology, etc...), but in SR thought experiments, it really doesn't. It starts at an event, and an event doesn't have an absolute rest frame. It's at rest in ALL frames, because it is a point. Doppler shift also biases the idea, but that's associated with 2 frames. A rando photon hitting an observer doesn't have an inherent $p_{\mu}=(|p|, \vec p)$.

Comment: @JEB umm, yes, the flash is an event which does not have a rest frame and does not have a velocity. But the statement was about the **train** moving, not the **flash**. The flash is an event, but the train has a timelike worldline and the light from the flash has a null worldline. Both train and light have a velocity (magnitude and direction), though the flash event does not. In the platform frame the train is indeed moving and the direction of the motion is indeed be towards one light pulse and away from the other. In the attempt to correct the bias you over-corrected.

Comment: @Dale we're gonna have to agree to disagree. But if the windspeed is the same and train speed , and bolts hit the train, not the track...it's the same situation in the thought experiment, but now the train isn't moving relative to the light, therefore: such considerations don't matter. That one scenario is natural, and one is convoluted leads to a Galilean bias...IMHO.

Comment: @JEB In the platform frame the worldline of the light from A is $(c t, c t - L/2)$ and the worldline of the train observer M' is $(c t, v t)$. The velocity of the light from A is always $c$ in the positive direction, and the velocity of M' is always $v$ in the positive direction. At, for example time $t=L/(4c)$ the position of the light from A is $-L/4$ and the position of M' is $vL/(4c)$. M's velocity is to the right and the light is positioned to the left of M'. So M' is indeed moving in the direction away from the light from A, in the platform frame.

Answer (score 0):

From the frame of the train, the platform is moving away from the beam from B and toward the beam from A.
The train observer deduced the strikes were not simultaneous because the light from each did not meet at the center of the train. They conclude that the motion of the platform is such that the center reaches the location where the beams from A and B meet.
This makes sense - it upholds the principle of relativity.
Assuming the observers are aware of the special relativity they know it is possible that they (each) are moving toward and away from the beams coming from A and B. But they also know that it cannot be true that both are undergoing such motion as this would result in the beams of light from A and B meeting at the center of both the train and the platform, (which contradicts the relativity of simultaneity) or it will result not meeting at the center of either, which requires the speed of light is anisotropic.

So, one or the other must be true for the laws to predict the physical outcome, the empirical evidence observed in both frames. Furthermore, the simultaneity which is the single event of both beams of light meeting at the center of the platform is, unless I’m mistaken, an event that must be consistent in all inertial frames of reference. So to uphold the relativity of simultaneity, one of the observers must not be moving toward or away from the beams of light coming from A and B.